# ANTLR IDE Unable to connect to ANTLR Debugger

Tags: antlr

I'm using ANTLR IDE plugin for Eclipse (Helios R2) on Windows 7 and I'm trying to debug via the Interpreter using the Debug (Java) button, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Execution was cancelled

Reason:
Unable to connect to ANTLR Debugger

Connection refused: connect
```

I've tried running Eclipse as Administrator with the firewall turned off but that makes no difference, has anyone come across this before?

Also the Run (Java) works sometimes but it can also come up with the same issue.

Cheers Carl

Comment: Using Java VisualVM I can see a process launched when I run the debug, the process is called org.deved.antlride.runtime.LaunchParser, I guess its failing to connect to this process for some reason.

Comment: Perhaps firewall issues? If you try the stand-alone ANTLRWorks debugger (so not as an Eclipse plugin!), does the same happen?

Comment: ANTLRWorks debugger works fine, is TCP used to connect to the debugger?

Comment: I have never looked at it, but I imagine the connection is done through a (Java) `Socket`, so yes, TCP is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the ANTLR error, I can hit Run and I was getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from LaunchParser's constructor (see source here - http://antlrv3ide.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/antlrv3ide/trunk/org.deved.antlride.antlr-runtime/src/main/java/org/deved/antlride/runtime/LaunchParser.java?revision=948&view=markup)

There was a space in the path to the test case file location, which was not being escaped, and the path was being split into an extra argument.
If I change the path to somewhere that doesn't have a space, I don't get the exception.

Comment: You could be onto something there, as it happens my path to my file also has a folder named with a space in it. I'll move the project so there are no spaces in the path and see what happens.

Comment: @EraserHead IRL, have you had any luck?